Google почта не принимает и не отправляет письма с моего smtp сервера
Поставил себе на сервер Mailcow, настроил. На ту же яндекс почту письма уходят без проблем, обратно тоже. https://www.mail-tester.com выдает 10/10. А с гуглом проблемы. Есть отправлять на гугловскую почту, получаю вот такое сообщение:

host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.150.26]
said: 550-5.7.1 [185.97.200.51] The IP you're using to send mail is not
authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the
SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. For more
information, go to 550 5.7.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError
38308e7fff4ca-30041b158f7si25122551fa.276 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA
command)

Когда отправляю с гугловской почты на свою, то получаю вот это:

The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. For more information, go to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720 [example.ru. IP: timed out] [mail.example.ru. IP: timed out]

Читал в интернетах что такое может быть, если твой ip в https://www.spamhaus.org, но свой ip я оттуда удалил. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно с гугловской почтой подружиться
UPD:
PTR запись для ip адреса есть, DNS настроен, DKIM и DMARK есть. Порты 25 и 587 открыты и проброшены в роуторе
Для postfics задана конфигурация на предпочтительное использование ip4 smtp_address_preference = ipv4

Судя по всему, этот IP-адрес даже не внешний, так что для почты он не подходит от слова совсем

@andreymal у меня статический IP-адрес который видно извне, в тексте ошибки я его просто заменил на IP

PTR-запись задана для ip адеса?

@Andrew Hobbit Задана

Может до гугла запрос пришел с ipv6

@eri получается, нужно попробовать отключить ipv6?
